# Create a generic data factory with multiple linked services

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-.net

Use Case: To create a generic data factory which can read data from different azure blob containers which has flat files into Azure SQL. I have created a data pipeline which uses stored procedures to populate the Azure SQL tables.

Issue: The trouble that I have is that I want to execute this data factory from my code and change the database and blob container on the fly and execute the same data factory with this new parameters. The Table names will remain the same on the Azure SQL side and the File name will also remain same in the blob storage. The change will the the Container or the folder name inside the Container which will be know before hand.

Please help me out or point me in the direction as to what could help me achieve this and if this can be at all be achieved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the parameterized datasets and linked services. Define parameters on your data factory pipeline (which you want to pass from your code e.g. container name or the folder name, connection string for SQL azure and connection string for blob storage). Once this is defined - you would need to pass these values downstream all the way till the linked service

i.e. something like this
Pipeline Parameters > Dataset Parameters > Linked Service Parameters

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhushan, thank you for your response, currently you can add parameters only for the Azure SQL but not for the Azure Blob Storage and hence, I had to ask this question

Comment: I see.. in that case can you confirm - what do you mean when you say "read data from different azure blob containers" - is your storage account going to be same and just the container, directory or file names will be different that needs to be parameterized or its different storage accounts which you are trying to connect at runtime?

Comment: Yes, the Blob Account is going to be the same, the containers and directories are going to be different.

Comment: ok, in that case the linked service connection to the storage account will remain same, however you would want to create a parameterized dataset which uses that connection, have updated the screenshot in above ans now. As you can see there that the dataset has parameters which are referred in relevant places.. the parameters to the dataset can be passed from the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will update this. I was not able to get the `ALT+P` function to work on this page and hence I was lost.

Comment: Sure, feel free to revert in case of additional queries or mark the response as answer above so that it helps others looking for same solution.